# Cannot open Device Manager in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, device-manager

When I try to open Device Manager in Windows XP, the following error message appears:

> MMC cannot open the file C:\WINDOWS\system32\devmgmt.msc.

Comment: Can you check whether `devmgmt.msc` exists in the location mentioned in the error message? Also, when did the problem start? Have you run a virus scan on your computer? Is Windows functioning normally, other than that problem?

Comment: Right click on "My Computer" in the start menu and select "manage", can you view device manager in there?